# Composite Foreign and Primary Keys

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to create two tables one that contains unique values of City and Country and one that contains values of City, Country, timestamp and VisitedDays. City and Country will be a composite primary key in table 1.

I have a problem with the below script which is that I cannot input a new row with city and country values that have been previously added to table 2. In other words, I cannot input data from a second trip to the same city and country in table 2. Is there a way to have a composite primary key and have multiple rows with the same foreign key values. Based on the error my problem is related with the UNIQUE declaration of the ID.

Error:

> psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "trips_pkey"
>   DETAIL: key (city, country) = (San Juan, Puerto Rico) already exists.

Note: I reduced most of my script for this question. In the original script the TABLE 1 (primaryIds)  is populated only when there is a distint (City,Country) and table 2 is populated with every log (trip). Also I didn't include the Insert portion of the script for the table 2 because it works for all entry except with the same (City,Country).

```
import sys, psycopg2

with psycopg2.connect("dbname='XXXXX' user='YYYYY' password='ZZZZ'") as outdb:
    cur. outdb.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE primaryIds       "
          "(                                 "
          "City VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,    "
          "Country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "
          "PRIMARY KEY (City, Country),  "
          "UNIQUE (City)                 "
          ");                            ")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO primaryIds "
            "(City, Country)"
            " VALUES "
            "(%s, %s)", (a, b))

    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE trips          "
            "(                                     "
            "City VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,        "     
            "Country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,     "
            "Timestamp TIMESTAMP,              "
            "visitedDays INT,                     "
            "Ids VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES primaryIds(City), "
            "PRIMARY KEY (City, Country)                 "
            ");                                ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for my problem.

`import sys, psycopg2`

`with psycopg2.connect("dbname='XXXXX' user='YYYYY' password='ZZZZ'") as outdb:
    cur. outdb.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE primaryIds       "
          "(                                 "
          "City VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,    "
          "Country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "
          "PRIMARY KEY (City, Country)   "
          ");                            ")`

`cur.execute("INSERT INTO primaryIds "
            "(City, Country)"
            " VALUES "
            "(%s, %s)", (a, b))`

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE trips          "
        "(                                     "
        "City VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,        "     
        "Country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,     "
        "Timestamp TIMESTAMP,              "
        "visitedDays INT,                  "
        "FOREIGN KEY (City, Country) REFERENCES primaryIds(City,Country) "
        ");                                ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `trips` to have a composite primary key of City and Country -  it should be `City, Countr, Timestamp` (if it lets you) or you could create a new field automatically called `tripID` which is the primary key and unique. I would favor a tripID.